# How to build commons-crypto package in Ubuntu?

Tags: commoncrypto

I have cloned the commons-crypto code from https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto. 
I want to know the build steps for this packages. Please let me know the all dependency for this package.

Answer (score 0):

We need to give an argument -D with architecture to build it for aarch64.

```
mvn -D aarch64 compile
```

openssl, JRE and java are required to build this package.